Potential of rectangular hollow conductor
Consider an infinitely long rectangular hollow conductor with edge lengths $a$ and $b$, whose walls are grounded. On the base $z = 0$, the potential should be $V$, and for $z \to \infty$, the potential should approach zero. Solve the Laplace equation for the potential inside the hollow conductor using a separation of variables approach.
I tried to solve the problem, but something strange happens and I don't know what is wrong with my argument. I derived the dirichlet problem:
$\nabla^2 \Phi(x,y,z) = 0$ for $z>0$, $x \in (0,a)$, $y \in (0,b)$
$\Phi(x,y,0) = V$ for $x \in [0,a]$, $y \in [0,b]$ (base)
$\Phi(0,y,z) = \Phi(a,y,z) = \Phi(x,0,z) = \Phi(x,b,z) = 0$ for $z>0$ (grounded walls)
If I assume $\Phi(x,y,z) = U_x(x)U_y(y)U_z(z)$, then
$V = \Phi(x,y,0) = U_x(x)U_y(y)U_z(0)$
$ \Rightarrow U_x(x) = \frac{V}{U_y(y)U_z(0)} = \text{const} $
For a non trivial solution assume $V \neq 0 $. Then $U_x$ and $U_y$ are nonzero constant functions and therefore it holds for $z>0$
$\Phi(0,0,z) = \text{const} \cdot U_z(z) = 0 \Rightarrow U_z(z) = 0$
With this, the potential should be everywhere $0$ for $z>0$, which wouldn't make a lot of sense. Can someone find an explanation why this is wrong?

Your solution is not separable. It is a superposition of separable solutions. This is why you look for more general separable solutions and try to match the inhomogeneous boundary condition. In your case, you have the boundary conditions:
$$
U_x(0) = U_x(a) = 0 \\
U_y(0) = U_y(b) = 0 \\
$$
and by separating Laplace's equation:
$$
U_x''+k_x^2U_x = 0 \\
U_y''+k_y^2U_y = 0 \\
U_z''-(k_x^2+k_y^2)U_y = 0
$$
A priori, $k_x^2,k_y^2$ are real, but to satisfy the boundary conditions, they need tot be positive, and you find:
$$
U_x \propto \sin(k_xx)\quad U_y \propto \sin(k_yy) \quad U_z \propto e^{-\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2}z}
$$
with $k_x = \pi m/a$, $k_y = \pi n/b$, $m,n\in\mathbb N^*$. You just need to expand the inhomogeneous boundary condition at $z=0$ in terms of the orthogonal modes to get the result.
